# reveal.js works from CDN, but not locally

Tags: javascript, cdn, reveal.js

This question deals with the `reveal.js` library, but is more likely just a general JavaScript question.  I have some HTML that loads the `reveal.js` library.  If I load it from `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/reveal.js/2.6.2` everything works properly.  I want to do some custom theming, so I am trying to run a local copy of `reveal.js`, however, when I clone the `reveal.js` repo from https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js and place it locally next to my HTML, ensuring that all the links are changed accordingly as well, it doesn't work (none of the text renders).  If I look at the JavaScript Console in Chrome, I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Reveal is not defined Lecture1.slides.html:29623 (anonymous function)
```

Comment: "ensuring that all the links are changed accordingly as well" --- when choosing between who to trust: you or chrome browser I would prefer the latter.

Comment: It's very straightforward, everywhere there is a `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/reveal.js`, I replace it with `reveal.js`.  Also, there are no 404 errors from Chrome related to finding the libraries.  It's only when loading the `Reveal` object that I get the error.  So I know Chrome is finding the library, just not loading it correctly from some reason.

Comment: "not loading it correctly" --- what does it mean? Chrome loads whatever you requires it to load.

Comment: There is an Uncaught reference error related to instantiating the Reveal object in `reveal.js`.  This does not show up when using the CDN library, but does locally.  Other than the link changes, there is no other changes in the HTML.

Comment: What is `reveal.js`? Is it supposed to be run the way you run it?

Comment: It's a popular JavaScript library for creating presentations.  Yes, it is supposed to work either locally or via CDN.

Comment: I know what it is. The question was - it's not clear where you got that file from and if that particular copy was supposed to be run standalone locally. How are we supposed to know if you just did not create an empty `reveal.js` and expect it to magically work?

Comment: See OP edit.  Added link to repo I cloned.

Comment: And you have followed the installation instructions haven't you?

Answer (score 1):

Reveal.js is running perfectly fine locally for me using only a few lines:

```
<script src="reveal.js/lib/js/head.min.js"></script>
<script src="reveal.js/js/reveal.js"></script>
<script>
//run reveal.js
Reveal.initialize({
    controls: true,
    progress: true,
    theme: Reveal.getQueryHash().theme || 'moon',
    transition: Reveal.getQueryHash().transition || 'slide',
    dependencies: [
      { src: 'reveal.js/lib/js/classList.js', condition: function() { return !document.body.classList; } },
      { src: 'reveal.js/plugin/highlight/highlight.js', async: true, callback: function() { hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); } }
     ]
});
</script>
```